# Authorize WebApi using Windows Phone 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a new project, i have an MVC web application on which im letting the users log in by using Facebook as a provider(oauth), however now i'm starting to develop for Windows Phone 8 and i want to make a call to a WebApi controller (which needs to authenticate a user before answering the call).

How can i authenticate the mobile app in order to make this request? I've been searching for tutorials but i haven't been able to find anything, i'm kind of lost, can anyone point me in the right direction or provide an example?

Comment: I can't find an example for this either. I also need to have other providers and a website frontend. Please let me know if you figure out how to do this.